# Broke my Pandas installation, can't remove the package

Tags: pandas, anaconda, conda

In a frenzy of copy-pasting, I accidentally overwrote the `_decorators.py` file in my Pandas installation. Now when I try to import Pandas I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File d:\dropbox\jim\astro_at_vuw\phd_stuff\code\combine_ned_gleam.py:1
    import pandas as pd

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:22
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:18
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py:4
    from pandas.util.version import Version

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py:2
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa:F401

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:7
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=' ', names=[

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I've tried to remove Pandas using:

- the conda terminal but I get `An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.`
- Anaconda Navigator, but when I click on `pandas` under installed packages in the Environments section, all of the options are greyed out.

I'm on Windows 10 using Anaconda Navigator v2.3.2

How can I fix my Pandas installation?

Comment: Can you `conda install --force-reinstall -n phd pandas`?